# Compile gedit 2.30.4 from git

Tags: makefile, gnome, gedit

I've tried to compile gedit from git but i can't. In the make process i get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./.libs/libgedit.a(eggsmclient-xsmp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'IceProcessMessages'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'IceProcessMessages' is defined in DSO //usr/lib64/libICE.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
//usr/lib64/libICE.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[4]: *** [gedit] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/thom/gedit/gedit'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/thom/gedit/gedit'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/thom/gedit/gedit'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/thom/gedit'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideia? Thank you.

UPDATE:

Actually i don't have it in the same directory. I don't know what to do. Thank you.

```
# locate libICE
/usr/lib32/libICE.a
/usr/lib32/libICE.so
/usr/lib32/libICE.so.6
/usr/lib32/libICE.so.6.3.0
/usr/lib/libICE.a
/usr/lib/libICE.so
/usr/lib/libICE.so.6
/usr/lib/libICE.so.6.3.0
```

Comment: don't remember what are the dependencies of Gedit but the error syas that a lib is missing (libICE). Try to check out http://rpm.pbone.net/ for the dependencies of Gedit

Comment: I do have all dependencies... This file is part of two Debian packages (http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=sid&arch=any&mode=path&searchon=contents&keywords=libICE.so.6). I just don't know what's wrong. Thank you John

Comment: hummmm if you have all files then maybe some sort of switch is missing (never tried to compile through git though) like -ice or something (a linker per say). Try to look for common git switches that link the libraries (maybe the error is here, even if the library is there, the compiler won't find it and/or link it)

Comment: I really don't know how to fix it John, thank you.

Comment: I see there was a 3rd option that I was unaware... anyways, I belive you're trying to install Gedit 64 bits version (has the error messages states lib64), maybe you should get the 32 bits version (or install the 64 bits version of the libs). Still, even after you have some sort of path problems try this : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-setting-changing-library-path/ ->WARNING! Changing a lib path can break stuff that is already installed!

Answer (score 0):

Look at following lines in configure.ac:

```
if test "$os_osx" = "no" &&
   test "$os_win32" = "no"; then
    PKG_CHECK_MODULES(EGG_SMCLIENT, [
        sm >= 1.0.0
    ])
else
```

which should start on line 319.  You have to change:

```
        sm >= 1.0.0
```

by:

```
        sm >= 1.0.0 ice
```

Then, you have to re-run *autogen.sh*.  Also, you can report the build bug and send a patch to gedit developers on https://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=gedit :-)